Failed to use MTWindow in Docker
I used the following method to open the desktop
xhost '+local:*';

The description of creating a Docker container is as follows:
sudo docker run -dit --privileged --name test3 -v /dev/bus/usb:/deb/bus/usb -e DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix/:/tmp/.X11-unix/ -v ~/Event:/Event --net=host openeb:ubuntu-20.04 /bin/bash

This is an error message:
root@LPA3588:/Event/Z1_annotated# /bin/python3 "/Event/Z1_annotated/test_onlyfind copy.py"
[SDK][ERROR] GLX: No GLXFBConfigs returned
[SDK][ERROR] GLX: Failed to find a suitable GLXFBConfig
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
self.run()
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "/Event/Z1_annotated/test_onlyfind copy.py", line 81, in main
with MTWindow(title="Metavision Events Viewer", width=width, height=height,
RuntimeError: Impossible to create a glfw window

What shall I do?
I am trying to run the test file for the event camera in Docker. Here is the relevant description file for MTWindow:
https://docs.prophesee.ai/stable/api/python/ui/bindings.html#metavision_sdk_ui.MTWindow

If you need a privileged container, with host networking, and a physical device, and you're bind-mounting the application code, can you just run the application locally without a container instead?

@DavidMaze I use Docker because I want to deploy my devices and drivers on ARM architecture devices in different systems. With Docker, I can package containers and publish them to various devices. If the functionality cannot be implemented in the end, I will still run the program locally.

A container is fundamentally an isolation system, and it's not necessarily a good match for a device driver.  It seems like you're disabling almost all of Docker's core features and just trying to use it for software distribution.  You might use the native Python packaging system instead, and distribute a *.whl file.
